# How to create a callable mock from a non-callable spec?

Tags: python-unittest.mock

I have two classes: class **One** that does some stuff and class **Wrapper** that translates the API of **One**. To test the **Wrapper** I want to mock the class **One**. My problem is that **One** sets a number of attributes in it's `__init__` method and I'd like my test to throw an error when these attributes are changed (e.g. renamed or deleted) in **One** but not in **Wrapper**.

I have tried to initialize an instance of **One** and to use it as a `spec`, but the resulting mock is non-callable:

```py
from unittest import mock
import pytest

class One:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

spec_obj = One(a='foo')

# working code, the test should pass
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, wa):
        self._one = One(a=wa)
        self.wa = self._one.a

@mock.patch(__name__ + '.One', autospec=spec_obj)
def test_wrapper(MockOne):
    MockOne.return_value.a = test_a = 'bar'
    
    wrapper_obj = Wrapper(wa=test_a)

    MockOne.assert_called_once_with(a=test_a)
    assert wrapper_obj.wa == test_a
```

which throws the error:

```py
TypeError: 'NonCallableMagicMock' object is not callable
```

since the spec `spec_obj` is non-callable.

If I set `autospec=True`, everything works but the test passes even when the **One's** attribute is renamed.

Comment: I've got the solution from ChatGPT but I can't post it due to the current policy of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`MockOne.return_value` produces a `Mock` that you configure, but when the mock is actually called, you get a *different* `Mock` that hasn't been properly configured. You need to configure `MockOne.return_value` directly.

```
@mock.patch('One', autospec=True)
def test_wrapper(MockOne):
    MockOne.return_value.a = test_a = 'bar'
    
    wrapper_obj = Wrapper(wa=test_a)

    MockOne.assert_called_once_with(a=test_a)
    assert wrapper_obj.wa == test_a
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer. You have combined two lines in my example code in a single one, which can indeed be done, but this doesn't change the overall behaviour, the mock is still non-callable.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `autospec=True`? It's not clear from the (simplified?) example why it is necessary. You don't need the real `One.__init__` to set the attribute value, because that's what `MockOne.return_value.a = 'bar'` does.

Comment: Yes, my code example is oversimplified. The actual classes have more methods called in Wrapper with more attributes of class One. The `autospec` makes sure that my mock indeed resembles the real object. Anyway, I've got the answer, see my comment to the original question.